# Configure Windows update through proxy?

Tags: windows, proxy, squid, windows-update

I have a squid proxy server and my clients are running on windows xp.
How can I make Windows XP reach the windows update sites through proxy?
In short, through the proxy, windows can not download updates.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It should work fine if your machines have your proxy set in the system proxy settings (Control Panel -> Internet Options).  Have you looked in your SQUID logs to see if there are errors?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply I already have done in internet option but still is not working and I had look in squid logs there is nothing for windows update, in this case what I have to do? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you investigated WSUS?

Comment: Harry the PCs were connected to WSUS on PDC after I have returned back to workgroup. also I have tested new windows installation but can't download the updates. it's really related to proxy setting

Comment: Presumably the machines don't need to use the proxy to access the WSUS server, so if you point them back at the WSUS server and delete the proxy settings (proxycfg -d) they should be fine.

Comment: This is in the past now there is no WSUS I have to connect them through proxy to download update from Microsoft site.

Comment: Does the Windows Update web site work?

Answer (score 3):

```
proxycfg -p <proxy>:<port> <bypass list>
```

UPDATE:
We see

```
2011-09-23      15:52:23:843     372    11c     Agent     * Access type: Named proxy
2011-09-23      15:52:23:843     372    11c     Agent     * Default proxy: 192.168.1.2:3128
2011-09-23      15:52:23:843     372    11c     Agent     * Default proxy bypass: *.local;<local>
```

in Windowsupdate.log, so it's configured to use proxy. Check if proxy is available from updated machine with `telnet 192.168.1.2 3128` and search squid logs, the answer must be there

Comment: I have already did it but not working because my proxy server has authentication user/pass how can I add them in proxycfg?Thank you in advance

Comment: proxycfg (or the ServerXMLHTTP API) does not support proxy authentication. Can't you just add an ACL which would allow unauthenticated access to *.microsoft.com or *.windowsupdate.com to your squid config? Would be the easiest route to go, I think.

Comment: Done but still not working :( what is the next solution?

Comment: Did proxy settings apply correctly? Does `proxycfg` without parameters display that proxy is used? If yes, check your squid logs, were  there any attempts to contact updates site?

Comment: Yes, I copied the proxycfg setting C:\>proxycfg
Microsoft (R) WinHTTP Default Proxy Configuration Tool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Current WinHTTP proxy settings under:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
    SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\
      WinHttpSettings :

    Proxy Server(s) :  192.168.1.2:3128
    Bypass List     :  *.local;<local>

Comment: Are squid logs empty? What's about `%windir%\Windowsupdate.log`? Windows update log contains proxy settings at the beginning, look [how to read it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093) One more useful link: [configuring proxy for windows updates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900935)

Comment: 2011-09-22 22:10:58:656  372 168c Misc  Microsoft signed: Yes
2011-09-22 22:11:05:781  372 168c Misc WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80190197
2011-09-22 22:11:05:781  372 168c Misc WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80190197
2011-09-22 22:11:05:781  372 168c Misc WARNING: DownloadFileInternal failed for http://download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/redir/muv4wuredir.cab: error 0x80190197
2011-09-22 22:11:05:781  372 168c Misc Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170

Comment: if you need more information please tell me how can I upload txt file here? thanks alot for your support

Comment: Clear log file, make one attempt to update, and use something like pastebin.com to attach log file to your question. And what about squid log? Does it contain some interesting?

Comment: Please find the new windows update logs http://pastebin.com/3UM2ixH2 about squid nothing interested

Comment: Add this to your question, nobody will read long comments

Answer (score 1):

I added the following lines and it worked great:

```
acl windowsupdate dstdomain windowsupdate.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain .update.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain download.windowsupdate.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain redir.metaservices.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain images.metaservices.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain c.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain www.download.windowsupdate.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain wustat.windows.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain crl.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain sls.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain productactivation.one.microsoft.com;
acl windowsupdate dstdomain ntservicepack.microsoft.com;
acl CONNECT method CONNECT;
acl wuCONNECT dstdomain www.update.microsoft.com;
acl wuCONNECT dstdomain sls.microsoft.com;
http_access allow CONNECT wuCONNECT localnet;
http_access allow windowsupdate localnet;
```